# Making a ajax call inside another ajax call if a condition from the first call is false

Tags: jquery

I have a script that checks to see if a data table record exists using a Ajax call.
If the result is true it display a modal window, if not true I then run another Ajax call.

The issue is if the first Ajax call is false the second Ajax call is not running. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hotelid;
    var boardname;
    var boardid;
    var lookupboardid;
    $('#DefaultDisplayID').on('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.progress-bar').css('width', '0%').attr('aria-valuenow', 0);
        }, 3000);
        hotelid = "<?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['hotelid'];?>";
        boardid = $('#DefaultDisplayID').val();
        console.log("BOARD ID: ", boardid);
        boardname = $(this).attr('data-name');
        lookupboardid = boardid.substr(10);
        
        $.ajax({ // FIRST AJAX CALL
            url: 'check_default_signage_avail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                HotelID: hotelid,
                BoardID: boardid
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    console.log("RESULT", result);
                    $("#BoardID").val(result[0]);
                    $("#ImageName").val(result[1]);
                    $('#default_exists_data_modal').modal('show');
                } else {
                    $.ajax({ // SECOND AJAX CALL
                        url: 'check_signage_image.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            DisplayID: boardid
                        },
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success: function(data) {
                            var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                            result = JSON.parse(result);
                            SignageWidth = result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayWidth"];
                            SignageHeight = result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayHeight"];
                            NewSignageDisplayType = result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayType"];
                            $('#NewDefaultSignageDisplayType').val(NewSignageDisplayType);
                            $(".signagealert").hide().show(300);
                            $('#NewDefaultSignagesize').html("Display width: " + result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayWidth"] + ",<br/> Display height: " + result["imagesizes"][0]["DisplayHeight"]).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting and error in console or is it simply not working at all?

Comment: @ ciekals11 Hi, No errors in the console

Comment: did you try debugging , where are you going wrong ?

Comment: It's probably not the issue, but you should consider renaming your inner `data`-variable, since it's hiding the `data` variable from the first call. You could call them `dataFromFirstCall` or `checkDefaultSignageData`,  `checkSignageData`. The same thing with `result`.

Comment: In the console (network) I can't even see the second call executing.

Comment: I have checked your code and removed w whole bunch of variables that were declared here to make minimal demo. I worked like a charm. Side not. When you declare `dataType: JSON` i think that you don't need to make `var result = JSON.stringify(data); result = JSON.parse(result);` because your `data` object IS z JSON object already. As @smoksnes mentioned it can be a problem with variable names

Comment: if you do a console.log of result.length before if (result.length > 0) {, what do you get?

Comment: @Remling console.log result before the if. VM7261:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1